# aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1 error while installing nassl

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, pip

I am doing docker image ubuntu:18.04 and then I install python 3.7 using below commands

apt update

apt install software-properties-common

add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

apt install python3.7

apt-get install python3.7-dev

apt install python3-pip

After executing above , I have python 3.7 installed in my container.

Now I try  to install nassl package using   `python3.7 -m pip install nassl`

But I keep getting below error :

```
Failed building wheel for nasslRunning setup.py clean for nasslFailed to build nasslInstalling collected packages: nasslRunning setup.py install for nassl ... errorComplete output from command /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='/tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-04vwk2w4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:running installrunning buildrunning build_pycreating buildcreating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/nasslcopying nassl/init.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/nasslcopying nassl/ssl_client.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/nasslcopying nassl/legacy_ssl_client.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/nasslcopying nassl/ocsp_response.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/nasslrunning build_extbuilding 'nassl._nassl_legacy' extensioncreating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nasslcreating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nasslaarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DLEGACY_OPENSSL=1 -I/tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/include -Inassl/_nassl -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c nassl/_nassl/nassl.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl.o -Wallaarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DLEGACY_OPENSSL=1 -I/tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/include -Inassl/_nassl -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c nassl/_nassl/nassl_SSL_CTX.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_SSL_CTX.o -Wallaarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DLEGACY_OPENSSL=1 -I/tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/include -Inassl/_nassl -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c nassl/_nassl/nassl_SSL.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_SSL.o -Wallaarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DLEGACY_OPENSSL=1 -I/tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/include -Inassl/_nassl -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c nassl/_nassl/nassl_X509.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_X509.o -Wallaarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DLEGACY_OPENSSL=1 -I/tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/include -Inassl/_nassl -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c nassl/_nassl/nassl_errors.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_errors.o -Wallaarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DLEGACY_OPENSSL=1 -I/tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/include -Inassl/_nassl -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c nassl/_nassl/nassl_BIO.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_BIO.o -Wallaarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DLEGACY_OPENSSL=1 -I/tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/include -Inassl/_nassl -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c nassl/_nassl/nassl_X509_EXTENSION.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_X509_EXTENSION.o -Wallaarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DLEGACY_OPENSSL=1 -I/tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/include -Inassl/_nassl -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c nassl/_nassl/nassl_X509_NAME_ENTRY.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_X509_NAME_ENTRY.o -Wallaarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DLEGACY_OPENSSL=1 -I/tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/include -Inassl/_nassl -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c nassl/_nassl/nassl_SSL_SESSION.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_SSL_SESSION.o -Wallaarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DLEGACY_OPENSSL=1 -I/tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/include -Inassl/_nassl -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c nassl/_nassl/openssl_utils.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/openssl_utils.o -Wallaarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DLEGACY_OPENSSL=1 -I/tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/include -Inassl/_nassl -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c nassl/_nassl/nassl_OCSP_RESPONSE.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_OCSP_RESPONSE.o -Wallaarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DLEGACY_OPENSSL=1 -I/tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/include -Inassl/_nassl -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c nassl/_nassl/python_utils.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/python_utils.o -Wallaarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_SSL_CTX.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_SSL.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_X509.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_errors.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_BIO.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_X509_EXTENSION.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_X509_NAME_ENTRY.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_SSL_SESSION.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/openssl_utils.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/nassl_OCSP_RESPONSE.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl/python_utils.o /tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/linux64/libssl.a /tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/linux64/libcrypto.a /tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/zlib/linux64/libz.a -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/nassl/_nassl_legacy.cpython-37m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/linux64/libssl.a(s2_meth.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/linux64/libssl.a(s2_meth.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/linux64/libssl.a(s2_meth.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)/tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/bin/openssl-legacy/linux64/libssl.a: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit 

statuserror: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

```
----------------------------------------
```

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='/tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-04vwk2w4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-lq46clo0/nassl/
```

Any idea could be wrong here ?

Trying to install nassl package